# How to implement payment to multiple stripe accounts in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe payment.
I have multiple items in the cart for different sellers, so should pay to multiple sellers.
These sellers are all connected to the master account.

```
const cart = await Cart.findById(record.cartId);
        const currency = 'usd';
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
          amount: Math.ceil(amount * 100),
          currency: currency,
          transfer_group: record._id,
          automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          application_fee_amount: Math.ceil(amount * 10),
        });
        let transfers = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < cart.items.length; i ++){
          const item = cart.items[i];
          const partner = await Partner.findById(item);
          const seller = await Seller.findOne({user: partner.user});
          const stripe_destination = seller.stripe_account.id;
          const price = cart.prices[i];
          const transfer = await stripe.transfers.create({
            amount: Math.ceil(price * 100),
            currency: currency,
            destination: stripe_destination,
            transfer_group: record._id,
          });         
          transfers.push(transfer.id);
        }
        const confirmedPaymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(paymentIntent.id);
        console.log(confirmedPaymentIntent);
```

Even this doesn't work.
Although this works, what I want is not this. It should be like what I did with one connected account.
Here's what I did for one connected account. this works well.
how can I convert this to support multiple account?

```
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          mode: "payment",
          line_items: [
            {
              price_data: {
                currency: currency,
                product_data: {
                  name: name,
                },
                unit_amount: Math.ceil(amount * 100), //stripe divides this number by 100 ------- they treat this number as cents
              },
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
          payment_intent_data: {
            application_fee_amount: Math.ceil(amount * 10),
            transfer_data: {
              destination: seller.stripe_account.id
            },
          },
          success_url: `${domainURL}/payment/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
          cancel_url: `${domainURL}/payment/cancelled`,
        });
  
        return res.json({ url: session.url });
```

Comment: From my experience this won't be possible... This would mean the customer would have to make multiple payments for each seller. I'm guessing you will need to do this "behind the scene"

Comment: First you mentioned `Even this doesn't work`, then you mentioned `Although this works` - so what isn't working, and what is working? 

Your business model fits the Separate Charges and Transfers fund flow defined by Stripe : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges where an e-commerce marketplace that allows a single shopping cart for goods sold by multiple businesses. You would create a charge for the total amount, then make multiple transfers to the connected accounts. Why do you want to create multiple charges on a customer's card for your business model?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, alex. I think my question is not clear. What I want to do is to apply application_fee at the time of payment and let the user to pay sellers not the master account using transfer_data[destination]. Is there any way to add multiple accounts and amounts to this transfer_data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code shows a Payment Intent integration with Separate Charges and Transfers. There are multiple things wrong with it but since you don't want this we can skip them.

Your second code shows a Checkout Session integration with Destination Charges. If you want to change this to use Separate Charges and Transfers, it's possible, but it can't work exactly the same way.

- Destination Charges trigger an immediate and automatic Transfer to the connected account. You don't have to do any of it. That's possible because the Transfer properties are set at the payment stage.
- With Separate Charges and Transfers, your payment and your Transfer(s) are .. well, separate. You have to manually create Transfers with the funds your *received* with your payment.

Note that in your first code, you never receive any funds by the time you're trying to create Transfers. While this would technically work if you have available funds on your Stripe balance, it's not really the way to manage those Transfers.

So here's what you should do:
1 - You have your Checkout Session code in one endpoint:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          mode: "payment",
          line_items: [
            {
              price_data: {
                currency: currency,
                product_data: {
                  name: name,
                },
                unit_amount: Math.ceil(amount * 100),
              },
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
          payment_intent_data: {
              transfer_group: record._id
          },
          success_url: `${domainURL}/payment/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
          cancel_url: `${domainURL}/payment/cancelled`,
        });
  
        return res.json({ url: session.url });
```

2 - You wait for your customer to complete this Session.
Preferrably, that would be with a Webhook endpoint listening to `checkout.session.completed` and `charge.succeeded`, though you can periodically poll the Session too.

Then, take the Charge ID you got from `charge.succeeded`, and do the following:

```
const transfer1 = await stripe.transfers.create({
            amount: Math.ceil(price1 * 100),
            currency: currency,
            destination: stripe_destination,
            transfer_group: record._id,
            source_transactioon: charge_ID
          });   
const transfer2 = await stripe.transfers.create({
            amount: Math.ceil(price2 * 100),
            currency: currency,
            destination: stripe_destination2,
            transfer_group: record._id,
            source_transactioon: charge_ID
          });
etc...
```

The `source_transaction` parameter is really important here - it's how you'll be able to create Transfer without the funds being available on your balance yet (they're pending just after a payment).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my question is not clear. What I want to do is to apply application_fee at the time of payment and let the user to pay sellers not the master account using transfer_data[destination]. Is there any way to add multiple accounts and amounts to this transfer_data?

Comment: No, only one. That's Destination charges. The only way to pay multiple sellers is to use Separate Charges and Transfers, or make multiple payments with Direct / Destination charges - which isn't great from a customer experience point of view